Link Manager generates inconsistent domain in the URL
We are creating the URLs with the following code.
<a href="@LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item)">@item.DisplayName</a>

And, we have site definition as
<site name="mysite" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
    hostName="uat-cd.mysitename.com|uat.mysitename.com|uat-www.mysitename.com|uat-cd-ds.mysitename.com"
    targetHostName="uat.mysitename.com" 
    scheme="https" 
    virtualFolder="/" 
    physicalFolder="/" 
    rootPath="/sitecore/content/Sites/mysite" 
    startItem="/Home"
    database="cdsweb" 
    domain="extranet" 
    allowDebug="true" 
    cacheHtml="true" 
    htmlCacheSize="50MB" 
    enablePreview="true" 
    enableWebEdit="true"
    enableDebugger="true" 
    disableClientData="false" 
    dictionaryDomain="{DSG565SC-3E3E-4BD9-BC98-E1CA464GG456}" 
    enableItemLanguageFallback="true"
    enforceVersionPresence="true"
    noIndex="azure-uat-cd.mysitename.com|uat-cd.mysitename.com|uat.mysitename.com|uat-www.mysitename.com|uat-cd-ds.mysitename.com"/>

On front-end it generates url sometimes with domain as uat-cd.mysitename.com,sometimes as uat.mysitename.com and sometimes as uat-www.mysitename.com.
My understanding is that when targetHostName is present then it should be used in the domain.
We have the custom link provider as:
public override string GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item, Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.ItemUrlBuilderOptions options)
{
   options.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
   
   if (item.Language.CultureInfo.Name == "en")
   {
       options.LanguageEmbedding = LanguageEmbedding.Never;
   }

   var baseUrl = base.GetItemUrl(item, options);

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUrl))
   {
       return baseUrl;
   }
   var urlBuilder = new UriBuilder(baseUrl);
   if (options.Site == null)
   {
       return baseUrl;
   }
   urlBuilder.Scheme = options.Site.Properties["scheme"].IsNullOrEmpty() || options.Site.Properties["scheme"].Equals("https") ? "https" : "http";
   urlBuilder.Port = -1; // removes port from the URL so the default for the scheme is used
   var url = urlBuilder.ToString();
   url = url.EndsWith(@"/") ? url : url + @"/";

   return url;
}

Not sure why this inconsistent behaviour is. I tried to peak into the Sitecore.Kernel dll but the code is marked as abstract. I also tried to modify the sitedefinition.config file with hostName as pipe | separated and restart the IIS multiple times to load the site but behaviour is not replicating because I was suspecting that issue might come due to hostName in the config.
We are using Sitecore.NET 9.3.0 (rev. 003498)
EDIT-1:
We did not observe this in logs but on different pages after the deployment. When we hover or click on the link it sends us to uat-www.mysitename.com, uat-cd.mysitename.com or uat.mysitename.com. This is not redirection as well because when we inspect element then in the DOM it shows uat-www, uat-cd or uat. Also, after a few (2-3) of the hours it gets corrected automatically to uat.mysitename.com.
We downloaded the complete App_Config folder to check the duplicate but everything is fine.

Is there a load balancer in play here? Are you 100% sure that you don't have any other active site definitions? Try logging the site resolution: Log.Info($"Resolved site name: {options.Site?.Name}, target HostName: {options.Site?.Properties["targetHostName"]}, hostName: {options.Site?.Properties["hostName"]}, item database: {item.Database?.Name}", this);.

We have multisite configs.

Yes load balancer is there.

How exactly are you observing the different urls on the front end? Is this in some logging or are you browsing the site yourself and seeing different links on different pages/components? If you have multiple site definitions, do any of the others have similar hostnames? Please provide as much detail about each other definition. Are all instances behind the load balancer definitely running identical code base / config?

We observe this on different pages after the deployment when we hover or click on the link it sends us to uat-www, uat-cd or uat. This is not redirection as well because when we inspect element then in the DOM also it shows uat-www, uat-cd or uat. Also, after a few (2-3) of the hours it gets corrected automatically. We downloaded the complete App_Config folder to check the duplicate but everything is fine.

Sitecore is not using the targetHostName when the context site of the target and the current context site are the same. When they are the same, Sitecore will use the hostName that was used to access the page the link is being generated on. Could it be that you are caching the renderings with these links and that the first access to these pages is happening via one of the URLs that is not the targetHostName (e.g. some warmup script or similar)?

sebastians suggestion seem the most likely situation. You can easily test this by taking one instance out of the load balancer. Trigger a publish to clear the cache, then navigate the site locally on the instance that is out the load balancer. You should see only one URL used

Sure! let me check.

@SebastianLay in my case the current site and context site are same so does this mean that in my case the sitedefinition (as provided in the question) has pipe | separated hostName that could be the culprit?

Well, culprit is maybe not the best label. Your site definition is a valid use case (as there are valid reasons why you would want the same site to be reachable via different domains). You will just have to take care when and where these links are generated when you are caching the result. In addition to Deans suggestions you could also disable the caching on the affected rendering and check if that fixes the issue. One long-term fix would be to extend your GetItemUrl method to manually construct the link using the targetHostName.

I tried to check warmup setting in the web.config as



This is still an alien.
